# CSS parent and child elements on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep my parent and child elements on the same line.

The structure of the website is this:

```css
.about_me_pic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.about_me {
  width: 700px;
  height: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_me_pic">
  <img alt="hmmm" src="/assets/jack_and_mom.png">

  <div class="about_me">
    <i class="fa fa-hand-spock-o">Hi, my name is Jack Burum</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this scenario the `about_me_pic` is sitting on to of the `about_me` content and I want them to be in-line with one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of being parent/child make them siblings, and because you are using display:`inline-block` careful with the [whitespace](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) that it creates. See snippet below:

#### Snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#wrap {
  width: 1033px;
  font-size: 0 /*fix inline-block gap*/
}
.about_me_pic {
  width: 333px;
  height: 337px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}
.about_me {
  width: 700px;
  height: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
  background:lightblue /*demo */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="about_me_pic">
    <img alt="hmmm" src="//lorempixel.com/333/337">
  </div>
  <div class="about_me">
    <i class="fa fa-hand-spock-o">Hi, my name is Jack Burum</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use `white-space: nowrap;` for `#wrap` instead of setting the width

Comment: I don't agree with that sorry, because the children will have the sum `width` of the parent `wrap`

Comment: I tried using your solution (I added a wrapper height of 1100), but am not able to get this to work. When I inspect the elements, `#wrapper` is taking on the same height as `.about_me_pic` and I'm not sure why. I updated my code to show you what I have now.

Comment: I just posted it. I was able to get the width and height of wrapper to be correct, but I still cannot get the `inline-block` to work properly.

Comment: did you copy my snippet? because my snippet is working!

Comment: I used what you had, just tweaked the dimensions for my elements and removed the wildcard margin and padding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102947/discussion-between-dippas-and-jbur43).

Answer (score 1):

You need to place `.about_me` outside `.about_me_pic` and maybe set a smaller width/height (if the total width is larger then the line, the second element will go in the next line.

```css
.about_me_pic {
    width: 103px;
    height: 137px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.about_me {
    width:180px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_me_pic">
  <img alt="hmmm" src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif">
</div>
<div class="about_me">
  <i class="fa fa-hand-spock-o">Hi, my name is Jack Burum</i>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thats how i had it originally, but it did not work. Tried again, same thing.

Comment: @Jbur43 - it is probably because your width is too large. Run my code snippet, you will see that they are on the same line with a smaller size.